# Which scripture tells to practice untouchability?

Tags: untouchability

Hindus in the past practiced untouchability. Which scriptures tells us to practice untouchability ? In which scriptures it is written to practice untouchability.

Comment: No scripture tells us to practice untouchability.It is a filthy by-product of superiority complex brought by the caste system with no scriptural basis whatsoever.

Comment: @Rāmachandra I have heard that races who ate cow-meat were considered as untouchable. It has nothing to do with caste superiority as all foreigners were also considered as untouchable.  Agree with you that it shouldn't be practised in present world as it can hurt the sentiments of people , at least not with people who at present don't eat cow.